# PHP IF statements and Multidimentional arrays accoriding to data

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write an `if()` statement that will prevent multiple things from happening according to the data that is inside of a multidimentional array. I'm having trouble translating this into code.

Unfortunately, `in_array()` doesnt work for multidimentional arrays.

---

If the student completes the quiz, in which the Quiz Score was >= 80, then it updates the data. If the student doesnt score 80 or above, then the script doesn't update the data.

What I'm trying to accomplish (when the user submits the quiz)

- If `$quiz_score >= 80` AND `$quiz_id` does not exist then run a piece of code
- If `the quiz_id` exists AND the quiz was passed (`$quiz_passed == 1`) AND `$quiz_score >= 80`, then run another piece of code that just updates the score (in case user retakes quiz to improve score, if new score is below 80, keep first score.)
- Else retake the quiz (meaning the user didnt score 80 or above)

According to the data, their should never be a row with the same `$quiz_id`

here is a graphical view of my data (the array):

[image]

Here is the array in code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quiz_name] => Quiz 1 - General Chemistry
            [quiz_id] => 1
            [quiz_score] => 100
            [quiz_passed] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quiz_name] => Quiz 2 - Orangic Chemistry
            [quiz_id] => 24
            [quiz_score] => 100
            [quiz_passed] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quiz_name] => Quiz 3 - Biochemistry
            [quiz_id] => 31
            [quiz_score] => 25
            [quiz_passed] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quiz_name] => Quiz 4 - Analytical Chemistry
            [quiz_id] => 47
            [quiz_score] => 80
            [quiz_passed] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [quiz_name] => Quiz 5 - Physical Chemistry
            [quiz_id] => 55
            [quiz_score] => 45
            [quiz_passed] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: And what is your question? Your description sounds pretty good, you should be able to implement that straight forward

Comment: Pulling the data from the multidimensional array. Basically search the array, to write the if statements. I tried using the in_array() function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not dynamically create a new/temporary non multidimentionnal array that will contain all the quizz_id from all others arrays ? so that you could use in_array()

Comment: user2196728 - I wouldn't know where to begin. I've tried storing them in another array, but it was a failed attempt. My syntax was probably wrong.

Comment: Loop over all your existing arrays to fill the new one

Comment: user2196728 - Once I store them in an array, how can I get the other data to write the conditionals. Do i have to store them in an array as well? Any code hints or push in the right direction would help and be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will this help (look at the end) ? http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-in_array.html

Comment: Not sure if that will help, as im also calling this code above, inside of a function already, which is a hook into a wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the scores were stored in `$scores`:

```
foreach ($scores as $test) {
  if ($test['quiz_score'] > 80 && empty($test['quiz_id'])) {
    // Run bit of code
  } elseif (!empty($test['quiz_id']) && $test['quiz_passed'] == 1 && $test['quiz_score'] > 80) {
    // Update score
  } else {
    // Retake quiz
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you meant by the `quiz_id` not existing, so I assumed you meant it was empty.

Also, I left the details for you to add in. If you need any extra help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do the job:

```
$input = array
(
    array
        (
            'quiz_name' => 'Quiz 1 - General Chemistry',
            'quiz_id' => 1,
            'quiz_score' => 100,
            'quiz_passed' => 1,
        ),

    array
        (
            'quiz_name' => 'Quiz 2 - Orangic Chemistry',
            'quiz_id' => 24,
            'quiz_score' => 100,
            'quiz_passed' => 1,
        ),

    array
        (
            'quiz_name' => 'Quiz 3 - Biochemistry',
            'quiz_id' => 31,
            'quiz_score' => 25,
            'quiz_passed' => false,
        ),

    array
        (
            'quiz_name' => 'Quiz 4 - Analytical Chemistry',
            'quiz_id' => 47,
            'quiz_score' => 80,
            'quiz_passed' => 1,
        ),

    array
        (
            'quiz_name' => 'Quiz 5 - Physical Chemistry',
            'quiz_id' => 55,
            'quiz_score' => 45,
            'quiz_passed' => false,
        ),

);

$result = array();

foreach($input as $v)
{
   $result['names'][] = $v['quiz_name'];
   $result['ids'][] = $v['quiz_id'];
   $result['scores'][] = $v['quiz_score'];
   $result['quiz_passed'][] = $v['quiz_passed'];
}

print_r(in_array(31,$result['ids'])); // 1
print_r(in_array('Quiz 5 - Physical Chemistry',$result['names'])); //1
```